# Magento: My custom extension don't load template file

Tags: php, magento, templates

I have created my extension. It's working fine. But the problem is, it won't load the template file. I don't know why?
So, guys please tell me where I'm wrong.

**app/etc/modules/CustomMod_Search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomMod_Search>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CustomMod_Search>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/CustomMod/Search/**

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomMod_Search>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CustomMod_Search>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <search>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>CustomMod_Search</module>
                    <frontName>search</frontName>
                </args>
            </search>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <search>
                    <file>search.xml</file>
                </search>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <search>
                <class>CustomMod_Search_Block</class>
            </search>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Block/Search.php**

```
class CustomMod_Search_Block_Search extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

**controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class CustomMod_Search_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/**

**layout/search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <search_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="search/search" name="dropdown.search" template="search/search.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </search_index_index>
</layout>
```

**template/search/search.phtml**

```
<h1>Hello PHP</h1>
```

But when I open the url
`http://localhost/magento/index.php/search/index/index`

the opened page dosn't have the

## Hello PHP

content in the content area.

I enabled Template path hint too, but it won't show search.phtml template anywhere.
I also tried `<block type="core/template" name="dropdown.search" template="search/search.phtml" />` but nothing happened.

Please friends help me. Tell me where I'm wrong. or suggest me the right way to do this if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77314/discussion-between-alauddin-ansari-and-dushyant-joshi).